# Adding 2 TD elements to a table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table on my web page that I wish to change using JavaScript. My main goal is to add 2 TD to a new row. Somehow after running my code a new row is inserted but all the data is in on TD, why?

```js
var table2 = document.getElementById("testsPieArea");
var rowCounter = table2.rows.length;
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var row = table2.insertRow(rowCounter);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cellData = "<tr>";
  cellData += "<td> Info1 </td><td> Info2 </td></tr>";
  cell1.innerHTML = cellData;
  rowCounter++;
}
```

In real life is see 2 rows being created but "info1info2" is written in them and that's not what I asked for.

Comment: Include a full; working example. Also, where are your using `i`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*cell1* (created by [**`HTMLTableRowElement.insertCell()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/insertCell)) refers to a cell (*td*), not *row*. You should insert into *row*:

```
row.innerHTML = cellData;
```

```js
var table2 = document.getElementById("testsPieArea");
var rowCounter = table2.rows.length;
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  var row = table2.insertRow(rowCounter);
  var cellData = "<tr><td> Info1 </td><td> Info2 </td></tr>";
  row.innerHTML = cellData;
  rowCounter++;
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table id="testsPieArea"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new row, with two values, you can create the elements and set their `textContent` before adding them as children.

```js
insertRow(document.querySelector('#my-table'), [ 'A', 'B' ]);

function insertRow(table, data) {
  let tbody = table.querySelector('tbody'),
      tr = document.createElement('tr');
  data.forEach(value => {
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    td.textContent = value;
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });
  tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: thin solid grey;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
```

```html
<table id="my-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col 1</th>
      <th>Col 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Row 1, Col 1</td>
      <td>Row 1, Col 2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```